# Colorbar properties

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a `contour` with a `colorbar` that has a small values `(10e-9)`. This value appears at top of the `colorbar`. How can I change the location of this value from top to bottom of the `colorbar`. I want to move this value beneath the `colorbar` because when I added `label` above the `colorbar` it overlapped with this value

I attached image for the figure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by first finding the handle to the color bar, then changing the <strike>`yticklabel`</strike> `ticklabels` property. This is a cell array of stings, one for each tick mark. You can fill in whatever you want to show there. The multiplier at the top will go away. With the `text` function you can add your own modifier anywhere you want. But I think it looks nicer within the axis label.

However, the simple solution is to change the units you plot. Multiply everything by 10e9 before plotting, then add a nano prefix to your units.

Comment: The property is just called [`TickLabels`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.colorbar-properties.html#property_d119e131053) for colorbar objects.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I guess I haven't used color bars in a while... :)